# how to add switches to commands in cmd

Tags: batch-file

hey guys very simple question, I need to know how to add an extension/switch into a command in cmd.
Also how would I do this to a command that I made? (batch file that is called when typed the name of)

Ex.

### Traditional

```
ipconfig /all
```

### Modifed

```
ipconfig -a
```

or

```
ipconfig /a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple example to go with the answer above.

```
@echo off
if /i "%~1"=="-a" ipconfig /all
if /i "%~1"=="/a" ipconfig /all
```

(don't call your batch file ipconfig.bat - never use system command names for a batch file):

Answer (score 2):

> Cmd.exe provides the batch parameter expansion variables %0 through
>   %9. When you use batch parameters in a batch file, %0 is replaced by
>   the batch file name, and %1 through %9 are replaced by the
>   corresponding arguments that you type at the command line. To access
>   arguments beyond %9, you need to use the shift command. For more
>   information about the shift command, see Shift The %* batch parameter
>   is a wildcard reference to all the arguments, not including %0, that
>   are passed to the batch file.

For example, to copy the contents from Folder1 to Folder2, where %1 is
replaced by the value Folder1 and %2 is replaced by the value Folder2,
type the following in a batch file called Mybatch.bat:

```
xcopy %1\*.* %2
```

To run the file, type:

mybatch.bat C:\folder1 D:\folder2

[Copied from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

create a batch file `mytest.cmd` with notepad and add the following

```
rem start parsing out first parameter indicated with %1
set parm1=%1  
set arg1=%parm1:~2%

if "%arg1%"=="a" echo A was the parameter
```

now arg1 will hold `a` from your example without the - or /

if you run mytest -a  you'll see `A was the parameter` 
if you run mytest -b you won't see a thing...

(as a matter of fact you see every single comand that is in the cmd file which is handy for debugging, try adding @echo off at the first line of mytest.cmd to get rid of the noise)

try at the cmd prompt `set /?`, `if /?`, `for /?` or `call /?` to learn more about the commands available.

Comment: good answer but im slightly confused. Could you present this with the example I gave and tell how it works? And how to run it. @rene